# SharpZip escape filename

Tags: .net, zip, sharpziplib

I'm using [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to create a zip file with an html page and images.  If the html file has a / in the name, it creates a folder (which messes up the image paths).

Example: If the html file should be named `Web/Design.html` the zip file will contain a `Web` folder with a `Design.html` file in it.

I've tried escaping / by replacing / with // or / but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Is '/' character is a valid for a file name ?

Comment: no, its not. i dont know why i didnt realize that.  i knew \ (backslash) was invalid, but i guess i didnt think / (forward slash) would be invalid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filenames can't generally have slashes in them. I suggest you replace / with _ or something similar.